# How do I save a cell location or address as a variable to use on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, location, cell

I'm trying to find the bottom row of data on my sheet and save the location as a variable to use on another page. I'm doing this so that I can copy something down to make the same amount of rows as the other sheet.

```
Sub Test()  
Sheets("Buy Sell Alloc").Activate

    Dim X As Range
    Set X = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

    Sheets("Invest #1- Intermediate").Activate
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    X.Select
    Range(Selection, "C2").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

This is my code and it works if I don't switch sheets but it gives me an error when I go to the other sheet. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to activate sheets to do this, you can copy directly:

```
Dim X As Range
Set X = sheets("Buy Sell Alloc").range("C" & sheets("Buy Sell Alloc").Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

Sheets("Invest #1- Intermediate").Rows("2:2").Copy
X.PasteSpecial
```

The problem in the original code is that selecting X does not activate the sheet that it is on and because the pastespecial command doesn’t include a sheet reference it pastes it on the active sheet.

Comment: You’re putting both copy and paste in the same line, was that your intent?

Comment: If you are doing a range, you might as well resize and set values equal to each other.

Comment: The problem with that code is that it then tries to paste the stuff on the Buy Sell Alloc sheet. I want it to past on the other sheet. I'm basically trying to make the invest sheet have the same number of rows of data as the Buy Sell Alloc sheet. But the number of rows will change from time to time

Comment: I guess I really read your code wrong. Don’t select or activate the sheets, reference them directly with your copy and paste (or .value =) commands, every time.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a helper function so I can easily call from anywhere in my code without repeating myself. I pass it a worksheet variable (i.e. which sheet to find the last row in) and a column variable (i.e. which column of the given sheet to find the last populated row in). You could further develop to pass an additional parameter of which last row method to use and then add code for those methods inside the function.  The function returns a Long value for the last row.

```
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```